About autoencoder's latent state regularity
Suppose we are dealing with the problem of dimensionality reduction of an input $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$, by employing an autoencoder, as a composition of the encoder and decoder map $\mathbf{x} \simeq \mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{x})$. Suppose the input is time-evolving i.e. $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}(t)$, and has a $C^1$ regularity on some interval $(0,T)$. My question is whether such regularity is preserved under the encoding, meaning that the latent state is s.t. $\mathbf{z}(t)=\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{x}(t))\in C^1((0,T);\mathbb{R}^n)$.
From a mathematical standpoint, the requirement is that $\mathcal{E}\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^N;\mathbb{R}^n)$, which should be satisfied by reasonable choice of the activation function (e.g. ELU, SiLU).
Intuitively, the autoencoder does not see the temporal relation between different time instances of the input, thus I do not see why it should preserve continuity (or even $C^1$) also in the latent space.
Are there works in the literature tackling such regularity issue?

I am not familiar with the mathematical detail or the literature here. My impression is that if the AE isn't aware that samples are part of a sequence, then it won't observe constraints in the temporal dimension (akin to using an MLP for sequences: shuffle the samples and you'd get the same result). Perhaps you could add an additional feature/column to each sample denoting the time step. If the AE is designed to respect the continuity of each feature dimension, then making the temporal dimension explicit would presumably force the AE to preserve continuity in time as well as in feature space.
